# Ehcache working only for one table in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I'm trying to use second level cache for two tables, but its working only for one table. My ehcache.xml configuration is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<ehcache>  
 <defaultCache   
   maxElementsInMemory="100"   
   eternal="false"   
   timeToIdleSeconds="120"   
   timeToLiveSeconds="200" />  

   <cache name="com.cni.Employee"   
   maxElementsInMemory="100"   
   eternal="false"   
   timeToIdleSeconds="10"   
   timeToLiveSeconds="200" />  

   <cache name="com.cni.Person"   
   maxElementsInMemory="100"   
   eternal="false"   
   timeToIdleSeconds="10"   
  timeToLiveSeconds="200" />  

</ehcache>
```

Only "Employee" class is being cached. I could see only one SQL query for the first time for the class. But for "Person" class, each time when I hit the web service, its showing the SQL query always. Do I need to configure anything else?

My Person class is

```
 @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person [id=" + id + ", userId=" + userId
            + ", courseId=" + courseId + ", courseValue=" + courseValue
            + "]";
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String userId;
private String courseId;
private String courseValue;
```

My select query code

```
public JSONObject getCourseDetails(String id) {

    System.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck", "true");
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();       
    try (Session session = factory.openSession()) {
        String hql = "FROM Person E WHERE E.userId = "+id;
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        List<?> results = query.list();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonCourseList = gson.toJson(results);
        System.out.println("Course JSON Data: " + jsonCourseList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: What's the query you use for `Employee`?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Employee emp = session.load(Employee.class, id); This is the query I'm using for Employee class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPQL/HQL is always executed in the database. Then the entities are fetched from the second-level cache based on their ids in the query result set.

In case of `session.load` method, the entity is fetched from the second-level cache by the provided id directly. There is no need to execute the query in the database because the id is already known.